# Can Notepad++ be made to open file links in itself?

Tags: windows, notepad++, file-association, protocol, links

In Settings/Preferences, Notepad++ has an option on the `MISC.` tab under *'Clickable Link Settings'* to the right, to *Enable* to open links found in the edited files. It underlines them and opens them on double-click. I've tried it with the  `file:///` protocol and it works, but it actually executes them according to whatever file-association I have set in Windows.

Is there a way, a protocol, or a way to "make" a (local) protocol, such that Notepad++ opens any kind of files (any extension), from these links in the document, in Notepad++ itself? (ie in another tab)

Comment: This is quite a late response... So you don't want to change your default editor to be Notepad++, you just want to enable links that are inside Notepad++ to remain in there when you open them?

Comment: @Jon yes, as you say! As an extra, even better if I can select which kind (protocol) of links to open internally (n++) and externally (OS). So I could select that only file:// links to open in n++.

Comment: I guess that would require a plugin to do that. Scanned through [Directory for Notepad++ plugins](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) but didn't spot anything like it, only the Explorer plugin which promises to open any file that is clicked in Npp.

Comment: For anyone out there as dum as me: I could not get this to work with file:// links. It is because I was trying "file://C:\SomeFolder\SomeFile.txt". It worked when switched it to "file://C:/SomeFolder/SomeFile.txt"

Comment: Remember to use `%20` as replacement for a space in the link, e.g. `file://C:/Some%20Folder/Some%20File.txt`.
It also works if you leave the backslash \ in the path as long as you have the protocol right: `file://C:\Some%20Folder\Some%20File.txt`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`file://` is an intrinsic protocol of Windows, so if you want to ignore the "whatever file-association [is] set in Windows," i'd suggest you use a dedicated protocol, say `npp://`. Then add this to your registry (using the corresponding path on your system):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NPP]
@="URL: NotePad++ Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NPP\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NPP\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NPP\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NPP\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: superb tip & funny results :D. depending on the path separator and number of directories I use, N++/windows behaves very differently (sometimes opening a folder in explorer?!), most combinations not working. Also I escaped `\"%1\"` in the .reg file.

Comment: Point taken. :"> I've corrected it myself now, but i think you could've done it yourself, considering it's a bugfix. ;

As for the inconsistent results, the programmer in me would like to suggest that you make a test app that highlights whatever it is that windows is passing to it as args[0]... :D

Comment: Does not work on my Win10. (With or without corrections for "(x86)" in the file path.) I guess I'd also need the workaround that [Luke describes in his answer](http://superuser.com/a/921997/389368).

Answer (score 2):

The given answer did not work for my Windows 7 Pro system. The parameter `%1` was never (correctly) provided to NotePad++ and it started with an empty new file.

However instead I started a batch file through `@=c:\soft\start-notepad.bat "%1"`
In this batch file I stripped off the `NPP:///` prefix from `%1` and replaced `/` with `\` inside of `%1`. From this batch file the start of NotePad++ with the modified parameter `%1` does work perfectly. Here is the short batch file code:

#### start-notepad.bat

```
set note=insert here the path to notepad++.exe
set para1=%1%
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set para1=!para1:edit:///=!
set para1=!para1:/=\!
%note% %para1%
```

The quotation marks `"%1"` around `%1` are not really necessary, because paths or filenames with spaces or special symbols will anyhow result in broken hyperlinks in Notepad++.

If necessary this has to be corrected in NotePad++ with e.g. `%20` for the "space", otherwise the hyperlinking of link `NPP:///c:/path/file name.txt` will stop after `file`.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ v8.3.3 (64bit, Win 11)
I am able to open file URLs in notepad++ with one slight modification.
The clicked file opens as a new tab in notepad++.
For some reason, I need to write:

```
file:///C:/Me/Documents/My%20File.txt
```

Note the extra slash after `file://`.

No other changes made