# internal links in doc-file to Windows settings

Tags: windows

I want **internal links** **to** various **Windows settings** in a doc-file.
For links to f. e. System-Recovery it should work this, which I already could find here (this forum), this solution:

file:///C:/Me/Documents/My%20File.txt

Which should work for ´**System-Recovery**´, I would think it is, in my case:

**file:///E:\WINDOWS\system32\Restore\rstrui.exe**

(If a topic at all:
Whether (from the properties the link to there on desktop) I have to handle with the
´Run in´ "E:\Dokumente und Einstellungen(name)" I just cannot imagine. Sorry.
This with as example for a link to there, which should already work so.)

**But** for f. e. ´**Computermanagment**´ the data in a link to there on desktop are as follows, also with ´file:///´ possible, please ?
Or ´just´ do a link to this link ? (If THIS is possible.)

**How to link to this ?**

"Target": **%SystemRoot%\system32\compmgmt.msc /s**

"Run in": **%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%**

(To this in the internet I could not find anything. For direct link creating: yes.)

(Does this highlighting help ?) Thanks the interesst.

Comment: Links in a doc-file? What for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I hope my edits can help.  
  
This works, but only for download onto desktop creating there this link first:  
**file://E:\WINDOWS\system32\sysdm.cpl** Link to System.  
  
But this not at all:  
**file://%SystemRoot%\system32\compmgmt.msc /s** Link to Computermanagement

Comment: With some searches now I discovering, that this topic is very mixed up.  
The solution with ´file://´ is from for html, but also in Notpad++, as said here https://superuser.com/questions/585758/can-notepad-be-made-to-open-file-links-in-itself.  
But whether it works in a doc-file, it depends on the doc-editor, whether it is able to handle links at all.  
In pdf-creators it appears to be easy.  
So I have to rework my request. Needs some time, please.  
(Note: Sadnessly - for overview - the 2 spaces for break-line does not work.) 
So, for my needs I will have to go on in html, I think.

Comment: So now reading this, seems to be the way into this direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page

Comment: @harrymc. I want to create an own list to my needed Windows settings. Sometimes therefor are files to call up, sometimes in an other format instead to a file, as to see in the request-post, but ´.msc´ seems to be a file also. For off-line use certainly. Best it seems in html, but which is to convert to pdf also.

Comment: A batch file seems more suitable.

Comment: This is an idea. Thank You. Have to go ´back´ into this syntax. Long ago. Could it be the call command therefor ?

Comment: If pdf-creators could be available as open source for free, this would be an alternative to not to have to use .doc or html. 
Because of .doc and .html are to convert to pdf rather easily, the .doc and .html would be the fastest solution to this.
When this would work at all, which seems to: not. 
The batch-format or also - for example, in my case - GWBasic I had to step in into the entire syntax use. 
As said, could be an alternative, but before to do this effort, I would like to know, how to do it - this, the request - in batch or GWBasic. 
Is it OK, saying it here so ?

Comment: Now I asked with AI. 
In GW-Basic not possible. In Batch only in DOS-mode. 
This is said would go - <a href="#ms-settings:network">Systemsettings network</a> -, but my browser denies this, in the way of no reaction. Which is OK, because I only want to convert it to pdf. 
(Here the AI chat link I used, if OK: https://www.ecosia.org/chat?q=ecosia)

Comment: I asked the AI in some ways until I did receive this "Here is an example of a Batch-File, which opens the System Control:
@echo off (line-break) 
start control ". (In german translated to english by me for here now.) Not quite what I am searching for. But a success so far already once.

Comment: @harrymc. Thanks the note the batch. 
This does it "@echo off (line-break) start control desk.cpl", but still with an error (wrong parameter). 
With this list (for Win10), sadly - for here - now just in german, this list will help me further, I hope: 
(.cpl, .msc and others) https://bits-meet-bytes.de/windows-10-cpl-msc-und-andere-befehle/. 
Now I like to go into the batch syntax. 
(Sorry, the confusing, testing here in XP, but meant for in the main for Win10.) 
Thanks the support.

Comment: Wow. Found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program.  
This does it (in batch, in XP; Win10 once see):  start "" control desk.cpl